# CSS hover effect not working on span in table

Tags: html, css, hover, html-table

After it did work at first, I (apparently) changed something in my CSS. After hours of research I still can't figure out why the content of my `<span>` now won't be displayed on hover anymore...
Can anyone help me, please? Thank you!

This is a snippet of my CSS:

```
td.matchbool {
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #fff;
}
td.matchbool:hover{
  background:#e2e236;
  width:400px;
}

td.matchbool span{
  display: none;
}

td.matchbool:hover span{
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 300px;
  border-left: 5px solid #e2e236;
  display: block;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

And the important HTML part:

```
<table><tr>
  <td class='matchbool'>
    <span>
      Some Content
    </span>
  </td>
</tr></table>
```

Note that on hover the background of the `<td>` does change.

Comment: Do you have the original code before you saw the problem? As it is, it's hard to know exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hiding the only element in the single row, single column table.

This makes the HTML collapse to save space for other controls in the page.

That does not mean that `hover` function is gone. It just means that the space taken up by the `span` will not be "reserved" as if it is invisible.

To make it more simple: if you want the cell to take the same space as it should when hovering over it, then I suggest you re-write your CSS to preserve the size of the cell, even if its content is not visible.

One way to do so is to make the font color white, but that is a lousy way.

I have included a snippet code to convince you that the cell is there, and hover works but you need to know where to point your mouse pointer. 
For that, I have added extra padding to the `td` and made it with a border so you know where to put the cursor. once your mouse is inside the border, the `hover` functionality will kick in and you will see the `span`

```css
td.matchbool {
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
}
td.matchbool:hover {
  background: #e2e236;
  width: 400px;
}
td.matchbool span {
  display: none;
}
td.matchbool:hover span {
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 300px;
  border-left: 5px solid #e2e236;
  display: block;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='matchbool'>
      <span>Some Content</span>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @l0w_skilled 's answer is simpler, but yours is good for showing what exactly is going on

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You explained very good what's happening. But I actually wanted 'Some Content' to appear in another box outside of the table cell on hover. I think I didn't explain that clear enough in my question. Could you give me another hint on how I could do that? That would be great!

Comment: Okay, I managed to do it by myself. Thanks again for your great explanation. It was very helpful.

Comment: I am sorry, i didn't notice your comment 6 hours ago, until now. I am glad you found my answer informative. @Nina

Answer (score 1):

Your span is on `display: none;` this means the td has no propper size to hover over it.

Try: `visibility: hidden;` or `opacity: 0;` instead of `display: none;`.

`visibility: visible;` and `opacity: 1` to make it visible.

```
td.matchbool {
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #fff;
}
td.matchbool:hover{
  background:#e2e236;
  width:400px;
}

td.matchbool span{
  visibility: hidden;
}

td.matchbool:hover span{
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 300px;
  border-left: 5px solid #e2e236;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With visibility instead of display it does work, but the original (not hovered) table cell now always has the height of 'Some Content', which isn't very pretty. Could you help me out on how I can fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found a better solution myself with display, not visibility, but thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

For `td.matchbool span` and `td.matchbool:hover span`, use the `visibility` property instead of `display`. An invisible element will leave its space for the mouse to interact whereas non-displayed elements cannot be interacted with the mouse at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
td.matchbool span
{
   display: block;
}
```

remove display:none from it and you will see the content

Comment: OP wants it to be hidden until you hover its parent `td`